# Sprite moves indefinitely in a direction or gets stuck in diagonals

Tags: c#

I am working on a gaming project with a base to help get me started. The base is overall extremely helpful, however there is a part of the code that confuses me as to how to manipulate correctly.

When this code is run, the player sprite will indefinitely move in a direction until the other key press is used. If a playerMoveY is added, it will get stuck moving in diagonals.

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            playerMoveX = -1;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            playerMoveX = 1;
        }
```

Comment: I think a bit more code will be required to understand your issue. First, how do you use playerMoveX ? is it a delta ? if yes, are you setting it to 0 once your sprite has moved ? how do you use it ?

Comment: playerXPos = playerXPos + playerMoveX;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your full code, it's going to be hard to say for sure, but it is probably because you don't have a `KeyUp` event to reset the move value.

Similarly to how you created a `KeyDown` event to use the `Form1_KeyDown` method, try something like this for `KeyUp`

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
        playerMoveX = 0;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        playerMoveX = 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that if the player presses the left and right keys together and then releases one of them other key they will stop dead, this can happen if they are changing direction quickly from left/right etc. Movement control can be fiddly sometimes

Comment: I see this issue, especially now that I have added a Y axis and wish to move diagonally. What is the easiest way of amending this?